# The components of the vector in a simple pendulum

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors

[image]

Okay so this has been bugging me. Every book I've read so far just breaks down the vectors in a position where the pendulum is pulled to the right like the picture above.
But it doesn't say HOW it did it? Like why are the components not the other way around? Does changing the angle by $\theta$ also change the coordinate x-y plane by that angle? 
If so then why the component along the direction of motion now is $\sin \theta$ ? Shouldn't it be $ \cos \theta $ because it is along the x axis?
This is how I am imagining the coordinate system to be and concurrently the components to be like:
[image: Coordinate system] 
[image: The new components]

**My question:**
What exactly am I doing wrong here? And why are the components the way they are instead of being the other way around?

Comment: Actually theta depends upon, what coordinate sysyem you have, you have take from which axis you are taking an angle, in general coordinate system we measure the angle along the x axis.

Comment: What you call the "x-component" does not have to be proportional to the cosine of the angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to resolve the force of gravity $F=mg$ into two components, $F_x$ perpendicular to the string and $F_y$ parallel to the string.

$\theta$ is the angle that the string makes with the vertical. So when $\theta=0$ you want to have $F_x=0$ and $F_y=mg$. And when $\theta=90^o$ you want to have $F_x=mg$ and $F_y=0$.

And at all values of $\theta$ you want to have $F_x^2+F_y^2=F^2$.

So $F_x = mg\sin \theta$ and $F_y= mg\cos \theta$ meets all of these conditions.

Comment: Okay so there is no actual restriction to let the horizontal component only be represented by $  F \cos \theta$ and the vertical component by $ F \sin \theta$?

Answer (score 2):

> Why are the components the way they are instead of being the other way
>   around?

Because if the components (sin and cos) were reversed it would not make physical sense.

Think about the tension in the pendulum string and the vertical acceleration of the bob. Based on the first diagram, at any given instant the tension in the string is $mg$ cos θ and the vertical acceleration is $g$ sin θ.

When the bob is at the bottom of the swing, the angle is zero, cos θ = 1, and the tension in the string is a maximum of $mg$. In other words, the string is supporting the entire weight mg. The sin θ = 0 and the vertical acceleration is zero and the velocity of the bob at the bottom is at a maximum. If the components were reversed, the tension in the string at the bottom of the swing would be zero and the vertical acceleration $g$, which would make no sense physically.

When the angle is 90 $^0$ the string supports none of the weight of the bob. The cos θ = 0 and the tension is the string is zero. The sin θ = 1 so the vertical acceleration is $g$ (the bob is momentarily in free fall). If the components were reversed the tension in the string would be a maximum and the vertical acceleration would be zero. Again, that would make no sense physically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it is entirely on us to choose the way the horizontal and vertical components are going to be represented as? What about the conventional way where you always let the horizontal component for say a force vector $F$ be $F\cos \theta$ and the vertical component be $F\sin \theta$

Comment: You can choose your coordinate system any way you like. You can designate angles any way you like. But when you assign trig function when resolving forces into their components, that assignment has to be consistent with physical reality. My own approach is to do reality check. I ask myself, what would happen if the angle decreases? Increases? Does it square with physical reality.?

Answer (score 0):

Because it depends on what you are calling $\theta$. In your version, you have swapped $\theta$ to its complementary angle (i.e. $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2 - \theta$), which swaps $\sin$ and $\cos$. It is always good to label your angles.